# Image field related problems while using in django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a following Banner class. Which is editable by admin.

```
class Banner(models.Model):
    name        = models.CharField(max_length = 128)
    link        = models.TextField(max_length = 450)
    image       = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'banner_images')
```

There are two problems.

1. When saving image it is saved with original file name. I would like to change it with some unique name so that is not clashed when image with the same name is uploaded again in the specified directory.
2. While updating the image, the first image file must be deleted. It is not happening...

Any suggestion will be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you find solution, post it as answer please. I'm interested in such things too :)

Comment: I don't know the best way to get the solution... If I will not get answer in due time I will have to workout my solution and will surely put it on here.

Comment: I have no time to test this, but deleting image can be achived with save_model() method. It supports pre and past save method, so you can get image link, call common save method which rewrite data in database and save new image and then, after saving, just delete file with common python methods. Or just remove image with data you have got before saving and then save model.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
from os import rename
class Banner(models.Model):
    name        = models.CharField(max_length = 128)
    link        = models.TextField(max_length = 450)
    image       = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'banner_images')

    def save(self):
            super(Banner, self).save()
            new_filename = <insert code here to change name>
            self.image.name = new_filename
            rename(static_path+'banner_images/'+self.image, static_path+'banner_images/'+new_filename)
            super(Banner, self).save()
```

I'm not sure if the super(Banner, self).save() called is required twice or not. The 1st might be needed to save the file, and the 2nd one to update the DB record.

Comment: Image is 'ImageFieldFile' object. Any idea how to get filename from it? Also, in your example you will lose file extension.

Answer (score 0):

1) upload_to can be a callable, on save you can modify it's filename ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to))

2) see https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/6792, you have to delete it yourself,

Answer (score 0):

Since I was having problem related to savings of image through admin I got following solution which answers all my queries...

- First I found that even though admin keeps the original file name, if the file with same name already exists, it keeps on appending a count as a suffix to prevent duplicate file name... for example, if same file is uploaded it is stored as image, image_2, image_3 etc...
- Second, while changing image through admin, it was not removing the original file. For that I wrote following code in admin.py. And it does the job well...

**Code:**

```
class BannerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        #Remove the previous file if the object is not new 
        #and new file supplied.        
        if obj.id != None and len(request.FILES) > 0:

            import os
            old_obj = m.Banner.objects.get(id = obj.id)
            os.remove(old_obj.image.path)
```

Hope this helps you if you have got the similar problem.